# Change notification sound using AccessibilityService

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have implemented an accessibility service that listens to notifications and is notified whenever a notification is triggered.
My question is: once I obtain the Notification object, can I set its sound to a custom sound?
I tried doing something like:

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("<path_to_custom_sound>");
```

but this does not work.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" R.raw.notifysnd);
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Comment: Hi, this is similar to what I tried, the notification isn't triggered by me, I just intercept it using AccessibilityService. what I'm trying to figure out is whether the notification instance I have is a clone of the actual one - in which case modifications will not work, or is there a way to update it in a way that will change the actual notification